# NetSuite Advanced PDF (Freemarker) source JSON from record and display values

Tags: json, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

In NetSuite Advanced PDF source JSON array of objects from custom field on Item fulfillment record and iterate and display the values on the PDF.

Assigning the JSON does not work.
`<#assign array = tranline.custcol_my_custom_if_field>`

Answer (score 0):

I found that to use `assign` will need to explicitly say its a `string` then `eval` to evaluate to an array, the solution is to add `?string?eval` then we can iterate over the objects in the array and display the param values.

**JSON field:**

```
[{"displayField1": "apple", "displayField2": "green"},{"displayField1": "apple", "displayField2": "red"}]
```

**Advanced PDF:**

```
  <#assign array = tranline.custcol_my_custom_if_field?string?eval>
     <#list array as key>
       ${key.displayField1} - ${key.displayField2}
     </#list>
```

Comment: Too bad they expose some JSON nodes (Jackson or Gson API I guess), but provide no FreeMarker `ObjectWrapper` that supports it. Anyway, please use `?eval_json`, as `?eval` expects FTL, not JSON. Even if they are mostly compatible, `?eval` will for example fail on JSON `null` literals. However, `?eval_json` was added in FreeMarker 2.3.31 (released on 2021-02-16), and NetSuite is maybe behind with their FreeMarker fork.